# How to enable Quick Fix in Eclipse using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, warnings, validation, markers

Is it possible to turn on the Quick Fix in Eclipse when I'm writing JavaScript Code?

I'm using the JavaScript Validator in Eclipse EE "Kepler". The JS Validator shows me some warnings like `Missing semicolon`, but the Quick Fix entry in context menu is disabled. Is it possible to enable this feature?

I know that a semicolon is optional in JS but I think it's *cleaner code* if there are semicolons.

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you write the code yourself, then you should put effort into putting semicolons yourself =)

Comment: yeah thanks Sherlock... but how should I handle code from other team members? :)

Comment: I can suggest Sublime Text 2 plugin, if you are willing to switch to Sublime Text 2 [Sublime Text 2 is a very nice IDE. I use it on a daily basis for web dev, while Eclipse - for Java]: https://github.com/LewisW/SublimeAutoSemiColon